# Api for Echo VR giving TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'orange_team_restart_request'

Tags: python, api

Trying to get api to work with echo vr (vr game). When I run "pipenv run python -i ./api01_noip.py" in powershell it gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Burke Office\Desktop\Echo VR\api01_noip.py", line 6, in <module>
game_state = echovr_api.fetch_state()
  File "C:\Users\Burke Office\.virtualenvs\Echo_VR-XzBXNY9o\lib\site-packages\echovr_api\api.py", line 49, in fetch_state
    return GameState(**self.fetch_state_data())
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'orange_team_restart_request'
```

The section in question I believe is from api.py and says:

```
def fetch_state(self):
        """
        :returns:
            A :class:`~.GameState` object representing the state of the current
            game session as presented by the API.

        :raises requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            This exception will be thrown if the API is unavaible. This might
            indicate that the user is not currently in a match, or that they
            didn't launch Echo VR with the `-http` option.

        :raises json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            This exception will be thrown if the data returned by the API is not
            valid JSON. Likely indicates a bug in Echo VR or in this library.
        """
        return GameState(**self.fetch_state_data())
```

Comment: What are the expected arguments for `GameState`? What's in `self.fetch_state_data()`?

Comment: @RandomDavis def fetch_state_data(self):
        response = requests.get(self._gamestate_url)
        response_text = response.text.rstrip('\0')
        return json.loads(response_text)

Comment: Please put code in your question so it can be formatted, never in comments. Also that didn't even answer either of my questions.

Comment: error shows that `self.fetch_state_data()` sends dictionary with key `orange_team_restart_request` but `GameState` doesn't expect it. You could check what you can get in `GameState.__init__` and what you get from  `self.fetch_state_data()` - maybe it sends too much elements and you should skip them or `__init__` should use `**args` to get every variable. OR maybe you shouldn't use `**` in `GameState(**self.fetch_state_data())`. We can't help you because you didn't show class `GameState` and method `fetch_state_data()`